# Implementing older Magento version support in upgrade scripts

Tags: database, magento-1.4, upgrade-script

**Background:** I have some upgrade scripts, which implement methods only supported by new Magento versions. Magento 1.4 lacks these methods.

**Task:** My task is to implement support of Magento 1.4 in these scripts.

**Solution:** Currently I see this as checking if Magento version is higher then something, use the existing method, if lower then something, use plain MySQL / some methods that exist in Magento 1.4 / Zend, that result in same.

**Problem:** It is hard to understand what plain MySQL corresponds to methods, which I need to implement.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to monitor the database for all scripts that get executed ?
- Is there a manual for Magento 1.4 methods that can be used in upgrade scripts ?
- Am I on the right path to solve this case ?

Comment: Is this for a custom module? Why are you worrying about Plain MySQL?

Comment: @brentwpeterson Methods used in the script currently are only supported by 1.6+, I'm installing this module on 1.4. Yes, a custom module

Comment: And you have tested a version that works in 1.4? Why don't you simple ask what version of Magento then execute the appropriate script?

Comment: There is no version of this module that works on 1.4. I'm rewriting the module to work on 1.4 :) So, the only thing that is not compatible are the upgrade scripts, which I am rewriting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Is there a way to monitor the database for all scripts that get executed ?

What I always do is add logging to my install/upgrade scripts. I place `Mage::log()` lines at crucial points in my scripts. I usually add prepend the message with info like the filename (`basename(__FILE__)`) and the directory name (= resource name, `basename(dirname(__FILE__))`). The message itself would contain info about the executed action and the result of the action (like the last inserted ID or a boolean return value of a method that was executed).

- Is there a manual for Magento 1.4 methods that can be used in upgrade scripts ?

I would suggest that you set up a Magento 1.4 and a Magento 1.6+ and add the module to both. If I work with multiple setups then I usually deploy the module into both setups with symlinks (e.g. with Composer). So when I change something to the module, it will change on both setups.

If you use an IDE with code hinting and you define your `$this` or `$installer` variable through a PHPdoc var definition (like `/** @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */`) then you can easily find out what methods there are that you can call and by navigating to them you can see what they will do.

- Am I on the right path to solve this case ?

I think you are and I hope we have helped you to get a bit closer to solving this.

Comment: You can also enable full sql logging in your mysql service. This will then log every sql thrown at the service. This is standard for me on a development box. I frequently tail that log file whilst busy with a debugger, using breakpoints. I can then step through my code, and monitor what SQL is thrown at the server as you step through the code.

Comment: @ProxiBlue, I sometimes use SQL logging to debug things and I get a huge amount of queries per page request. In this case I only need one line indicating if an install/upgrade script has ran. But you got a good point here.

Comment: Hence the use of the debugger, and breakpoints ;) - I can then control the code execution, and see the SQL that was run as I step over each line of code.